# Identify hard drive in Time Capsule

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, airport, time-capsule

I have Time Capsule of the 1st generation (the flat one) wherein I changed the hard drive for one with 3TB capacity. This was 2 years ago. Now, the time having passed, I don't have any information regarding the hard disk I put into my Time Capsule and I would like to know exact, specific type of hard drive that resides therein.
I tried using Disk Utility but it won't display any information regarding Time Capsule. I also tried Airport Utility but I could not find any information regarding the hard drive type and manufacturer.
Would should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could open up your Time Capsule and take a look at the product label on the drive. Or if you bought it online you could look for the order details in your email archive or on the retailer’s website.

Comment: I wanna do it using my mac